# Help with a number histogram in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a histogram that will take two lists as values ([x],[y]). The program will then compare the two lists and create a new list [z] where z1 is the number of values in x that are smaller then or equal to y1, zk+1 is the number of values in x that are greater than yk, zi (for 1 < i < k+1) is the number of values in x that are greater than bi and smaller than or equal to bi+1. That means that the list of values y defines a set of bins;  assume that the list y is sorted in ascending order. The function Histogram counts (and returns) how many samples (x) fall into each bin.

Comment: What have you accomplished so far?

Comment: I wish SO was around when I had homework...

Answer (score 0):

First step:

```
def howManyIn(x, lo, hi):
    return sum(lo<i<=hi for i in x)

howManyIn([1,2,3,4,5], 2, 4)  # -> 2
```